# AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided at colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to create music by using AI. Finally, I found this page: https://towardsdatascience.com/ai-tunes-creating-new-songs-with-artificial-intelligence-4fb383218146

However, this program uses the open AI API, but when I copy and paste the API(I already had an Open AI's account), I get this error. I'm new to this program, so I don't know how to deal with it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rZd3.png)

this is the page https://colab.research.google.com/github/robgon-art/ai-tunes/blob/main/AI_Tunes_Generate_Music.ipynb

My code

```
#@title **Generate a new Song Title and Band Name**
#@markdown This data will be used to prompt the AI-Tunes system to create the song.
response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="davinci-instruct-beta",
  prompt="Create a new song title a new band name. Be creative!\n\nBand name:love The Execs\nSong title: love you more\n###\n\nBand name: The One Chords\nSong title: Moving Down to L.A\n###",
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=64,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0.5,
  presence_penalty=0.5,
  stop=["###"]
)

# print(response)

song_metadata = response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()
lines = song_metadata.split("\n")
generated_metadata = {}
song_title = "Our Random Song"
band_name = "Some Random Band"
for line in lines:
  parts = line.split(":")
  if len(parts) == 2:
    if "song title" in parts[0].lower() and len(parts[1]) > 0:
      song_title = parts[1].strip()
    if "band name" in parts[0].lower() and len(parts[1]) > 0:
      band_name = parts[1].strip()

print("Song Title:", song_title)
print("Band Name :", band_name)
```

First I check my API is correct. and go to the OpenAI FAQ

website.https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6882433-incorrect-api-key-provided

But still failed it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you used the following as the key:

```py
openai.api_key = "<sk-...>"
```

which should be

```py
openai.api_key = "sk-..."
```